# How to clear the costmap from other nodes (navigation2)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I clear the costmap of navigation2 from other nodes?
Environment ROS2 Eloquent.
When I was in ROS1, I could clear the costmap by calling the service.
Is it possible to do the same in ROS2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395524/how-to-clear-the-costmap-from-other-nodes-(navigation2)/) by [hamada](https://answers.ros.org/users/36638/hamada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2022-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indeed, we have services that implement the following messages: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_msgs/srv

Included there are full and partial costmap clearing operations. You can see an example of these in use in the BT navigator's clearing costmap BT node plugins. That's where we handle that logic in Nav2 rather than `move_base`. You can see a pythonic example in the `nav2_simple_navigator` I added last year which implements the core action APIs for using Nav2 in python without worrying about the ROS details (for the basic use-case): https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_simple_commander/nav2_simple_commander/robot_navigator.py#L293-L300

Eloquent is very old and unsupported now however, though the BT node was one of the first we added so it should be available in Eloquent (but you wouldn't have other extremely significant new features and bug fixes in Eloquent). Please upgrade to at least Galactic, by my personal recommendation. These features are worth it.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hamada](https://answers.ros.org/users/36638/hamada/) on 2022-02-02**:
Thanks! I will refer to it.
We are going to update to Foxy in our product in the future.
Is Galactic better than Foxy?
The EOL seems to be longer with Foxy.
Do you have any articles that can help me?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-02-02**:
Yes, Galactic fixes a TON of problems across the ecosystem, not just in Nav2. Plus, Nav2 has essentially dropped maintenance of Foxy due to the number and scale of changes between it and the bleeding edge development. There are still tons of things that cannot and aren't going to be backported to Foxy due to the speed of new development.